# Pass php variable value, from xls to another php script

Tags: php, xslt-2.0

How do I pass a PHP variable value ($regis), from XSL  post URL, here is part of the code of XSL, to another PHP script

```
<xsl:if test="item">
   <form method="POST" action="../checkout_food.php?regis=$regis">
    <input type="submit" value="PAYNOW" />
  </form>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: `checkout_food.php?regis=<?=$regis;?>`

Comment: It doesn't works, the $regis came from another PHP script ?